# Header CSS breaking

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty terrible at CSS/design so I'm struggling with some CSS here.

The page looks fine when loaded in a full screen browser at 1920x1080, however, as soon as you minimise or load the page on a mobile device the header content completely loses its placing but the body is fine.

Here's the CSS elements in question:

```
#header { 
background: url(assets/header_bckg.gif) repeat-x ; height:120px;  
}

#logo { display:inline-block; float:mid-left; padding:50px 0 0 570px; }
#logo { color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; height:12px; font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase;}


#login { display:inline-block; float:mid-right; padding-left:400px; padding-bottom: 7px; vertical-align:middle;}
#login{ color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; height:12px; font-size:12px; text-transform:uppercase;}


#avatar { display:inline-block; position:absolute; margin-top:28px; float:mid-right; padding-left: 505px; padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align:middle; }

#avatar_online {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7BAFD6 5%, #506D92 95%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #545454;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
    }

#avatar_offline {   
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #706C6B 5%, #4E4D4D 95%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #545454;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
    }
    #avatar_playing {   
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9BC861 5%, #789E4C 95%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: none;
        height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #545454;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
    }

#menu {position: absolute; margin-left:550px; top:88px; color:#fff; text-align:center; margin-top:0px;}
#menu ul{ width:800px; margin:0 auto;list-style:none; padding:0; text-align:left;}
#menu ul li{display:inline}
#menu ul a { float:left; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none; color:#fff; padding:8px 10px; width:118px; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; background:url(assets/menu_active.gif) no-repeat bottom center; color:#232323; }
#menu ul a:hover { 
    color: #85B0DF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

As always, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: in css there are no such things as `float:mid-left;`

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.  Can you put the whole thing in a jsfiddle?

Comment: It looks like the first issue is that you're using invalid CSS: there are only two values that the float property will accept: `right` or `left`. Also, posting your HTML would help us better diagnose your issue(s).

Answer (score 2):

1. **Make sure your CSS and HTML are valid.** As others have pointed out, there is no such thing as `float:mid-left`. Also, if your jsfiddle is indicative of your HTML, you're probably throwing browsers into [quirksmode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), because your HTML isn't structured properly (your first three tags need to be wrapped in a `<head>` tag, everything needs to be wrapped in an `<html>` tag, and the very first line should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`). Use the W3C's [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to ensure your code is correct. Only then can you begin to fix other issues.
2. **Learn what the various CSS declarations do.** While your CSS may be valid, it doesn't mean it's right. This: `#avatar { display:inline-block; position:absolute; margin-top:28px; float:mid-right; padding-left: 505px; padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align:middle; }` will technically validate once the float part is fixed. However, `position: absolute` and `float` are mutually exclusive -- float doesn't work when `position` is absolute or fixed. It will also help to learn how `padding` and `margin` affect the positioning of the element, and how they differ from one another. Finally, `vertical-align` doesn't work at all unless the element is a table cell, or `display` is set to `table-cell` (and the table-related set of display properties has its own quirks, so you can't necessarily just throw `display: table-cell` on an element and expect it to work a certain way).
3. **Learn how elements naturally behave, so that you can work *with* them, instead of against them.** Make sure you know how block, inline, and inline-block elements behave, and then work with them to get the layout you want, instead of throwing `display: inline-block` on everything and hoping for the best. The same goes for things like links (which will naturally have `cursor: pointer` on hover, unless you've disabled it elsewhere). Doing this will substantially clean up your CSS, making it easier to maintain. It may also clean up your HTML, as you find out what wrapper elements you truly need or can do without.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to tell what the intended result should be at smaller or "mobile" widths, even with the screenshots that you included above.

It looks like there are a number of issues with your HTML, too. Be careful with things like the `<font>` tag (it's deprecated as of HTML4).

That said, fixing things in your CSS such as `float: mid-right` and `float: mid-left`, which are both invalid, should help a bit. Additionally, you might want to investigate [CSS positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) - specifically, you'll likely want to use `position: relative` on your `#header` div.

Take a look at this [slightly cleaned up version of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/AUren/2/) - with background colors added to see where the header ends and  what space the navigation occupies.

Comment: To clarify, I'm aiming to keep the logo/menu/header content (avatar/login) all centered with the body of the page regardless of the view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple issues but it is hard to tell without seeing your HTML as well.  For starters, `#menu { margin-left:550px; }` is going to be part of the problem if you are trying to align on the left edge..  You should also know that `float:mid-right;` is not valid CSS.  Check out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp for more information on `float`.

**EDIT AFTER JSFIDDLE**

Put your `<div id='header'>` inside of your `<div id='main'>` and change your `#menu` css to be:
`

```
#menu { margin: 0px auto; top:88px; color:#fff; text-align:center; width:800px;}
#menu ul{list-style:none; padding:0; text-align:left;}
```

`

Since you already have a width defined on your menu, you can use `margin: 0 auto;` to keep it centered based on window size.  This will allow you to remove your `margin-left` and keep it from being pushed to the right.